# React typescript props not showing as possibly defined, even when I use '?' optional operator and '| undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My linter seems to have stopped flagging possibly undefined properties passed into my React components. For example:

```js
    interface BooleanTypeObject {
        prop1: true
    }
    
    interface MyComponentProps {
        disabledObject?: BooleanTypeObject | undefined;
    }
    
    export function MyComponent({
        disabledObject
    }: MyComponentProps): ReactElement {
    ...
    }
```

If I try to access `prop1` within my component, I get no linter errors. But I do when the code is compiled if the `disabledObject` is `undefined`. I'm sure it used to work fine when I used the `?` operator, or specified with `| undefined`.

I would have expected to see `(parameter) disabledObject: BooleanTeeTypeObj | undefined` here instead.

[image: screenshot]

All of my other linting seems to be working for typescript still. Can anyone think what's happening?

**tsconfig.json**

```js
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "ES2018",
            "module": "commonjs",
            "checkJs": false,
            "jsx": "react",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "strict": false,
            "noImplicitAny": false,
            "noUnusedLocals": false,
            "noUnusedParameters": false,
            "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
            "esModuleInterop": true,
            "skipLibCheck": true,
            "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    }
```

Comment: I've not seen a components props declared as `MyComponent({disabledObject}: MyComponentProps)` before. Is that attempting to destructure the props? And have you tried using the conventional `MyComponent(props: MyComponentProps)`? (You can then destructure inside the component function if you like)

Comment: Do you have `strictNullChecks` or `strict` enabled in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Алексей Мартинкевич I've added the tsconfig to the post. I have strict set to false. strictNullChecks is default. Should this matter? I feel like last week I was working with the same tsconfig.json settings and this wasn't an issue. I'm very possibly wrong about that though! (@DBS, I use both destructuring patters fine. There's nothing wrong with the way I'm destructuring in this instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have `strictNullChecks: false`. When it is set to false typescript ignores `null` and `undefined` entirely and `BooleanTypeObject | undefined` is equivalent to `BooleanTypeObject`.
If you want typescript to shown an error, you need to set it to `strictNullChecks: true`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks